# how to stop backward redirecting after logout called in JSP?

Tags: facebook, jsp, redirect, servlets, browser-cache

I need to stop users redirecting backward after logout. I tried to stop backward redirecting using following methods,

1) changed header `cache-control` to `no-cache,no-store` using servlet.
    But it only worked when use a servlet toredirect to a page.

2) Then i used a servlet filter to do the same task

```
doFilter(){
   HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
   httpResponse.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
   httpResponse.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
   httpResponse.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
}
```

3) Using meta tags to clear cache

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

When I redirect backward to a normal page like `index` , I ca still see login details in headers (Username, cart etc..)

Finally I tried disabling cache in developer tools and it worked. That's not practical.

How do I stop redirecting backward (Like in facebook) ?

Thank you.

Comment: *"When I redirect backward to a normal page like index , I ca still see login details in headers (Username, cart etc..)"*  You mean you're storing this stuff in a cookie rather than in the server-side session?  Then stop doing that.

Answer (score -1):

Set up those cache controls using response.setHeader() methods

```
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); 
response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
```